# How to run "find -exec <script> {}\;

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, find

I have a script that changes the properties of the files for a folder.

Here is the example tree:

```
dir 1
    --file 1
    --file 2
    --file 3
dir 2
    --file 1
    --file 2
dir 3
    --file 1
    --file 2
    --file 3
```

I am running this command on the terminal for which I wan to run the shell script (script.sh) for every directory

```
find . -type d -exec ./script.sh {}\;
```

it does not run and errors' this:

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are missing the space between `{}` and `;` :

```
find . -type d -exec ./script.sh {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
find . -type d -exec /path/to/script.sh '{}' \;
```

or

```
find . -type d -exec /path/to/script.sh \{\} \;
```

or (i believe it will work too, as "}" is unambiguously not special in that case, hence literral) :

```
find . -type d -exec /path/to/script.sh \{} \;
```

Comment: I 1) added quotes around `{}` to avoid the shell to interpret `{}` as "launch something in the current shell" instead of the literral "{}" string.  2) added a space after it so that exec sees the expected ";" indicating the end of the exec command (that was the point making it "barf" to you)  3) put full path to the script to launch, to avoid confusion (reader and/or program) about which script is launched...